# r contrast sum coding

Tags: r, regression

I'm doing binomial regression with a dataset and two of the independent variables are factors with quite a large number of levels (26 and 9). I want to be able to see the effect of each different level of each factor on the dependent variable - for neither factor is there a level which makes a logical "default" to which to compare, and for both I'm interested the relative effect of *all* levels. My understanding is that therefore I want to use sum contrasts for both of these so that the coefficients for each factor level are compared with the grand mean, rather than with one of the other levels. I can do this with code like:

```
model<-glm(dependent_variable~factor1+factor2+..., data=dataset,family="binomial",contrasts=list(factor1=contr.sum,factor2=contr.sum));
```

However, this still ignores the reference level for each factor, returning 25 and 8 coefficients respectively instead of 26 and 9. Why is this so? And is there any way to get it to show a coefficient for the reference value too?

I have been through guides elsewhere on the internet (such as http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm), and these show the same behaviour, but don't explain why, if each factor level is being compared to the grand mean rather than to a reference level, one level needs to be excluded. I've previously used different implementations of logistic regression (such as the "VARBRUL" package used a lot in linguistics) which return separate coefficients for every level, so I assume this should also be possible somehow here?

For reference, my actual code looks like:

```
glm_everything<-glm(perceptually.rhotic~vowel+modified_clip_start+open_syllable+prepausal+speaker,data=rhoticity_prepped_for_glm_exclude_nonrhotic_speakers,family="binomial",contrasts = list(speaker=contr.sum,vowel=contr.sum));
```

and a sample of my data looks like:

```
     perceptually.rhotic       vowel modified_clip_start open_syllable prepausal speaker
2633                TRUE       START           1912.1854         FALSE     FALSE       8
6709                TRUE      SQUARE            212.0000          TRUE     FALSE      b7
6468                TRUE      lettER           2114.0000          TRUE      TRUE      b6
6464                TRUE NORTH~FORCE           2050.0000          TRUE      TRUE      b6
6039                TRUE       NURSE           3301.0000          TRUE      TRUE      b5
4429                TRUE NORTH~FORCE           2051.0000          TRUE      TRUE     b13
556                 TRUE      lettER            200.9126         FALSE      TRUE      19
1212                TRUE      lettER            584.8842          TRUE     FALSE      23
2061                TRUE        NEAR           1494.7303          TRUE     FALSE       3
1411                TRUE NORTH~FORCE            201.1348         FALSE     FALSE      25
```

Thanks very much in advance for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: check out the `lsmeans` or `effects` packages

Comment: thanks very much! I'll look into those